# d3 histogram doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw an histogram using `d3.js`, but it doesn't show anything, I don't know whats's wrong with my following code `histogram.js`, the data is available [here](https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/eagan/class/igr204/data/france.tsv):

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40};
    width = 460 //- margin.left - margin.right;
    height = 400 //- margin.top - margin.bottom;

//var height_histogram = 200,
  //width_histogram = 700;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
let svg = d3.select("#histogram-density")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");




d3.tsv("data/france.tsv")
  .row((d,i)=> {
    return {
      codePostal: +d["Postal Code"],
      inseeCode : +d.inseecode,
      place: d.place,
      longitude: +d.x,
      latitude: +d.y,
      population: +d.population,
      density: +d.density
    };
  })
  .get((error,rows) => {
    console.log("Loaded "+ rows.length + " rows");

            //console.log("First row", rows[0]);
            //console.log("Last  row", rows[rows.length-1]);
            //console.log("First row", rows[4]);
            //console.log("First row", rows[2992]);
            //console.log("First row", rows[2399]);
            //console.log("First row", rows[1200]);
            //console.log("First row", rows[20000]);

            dataset = rows.filter(function(row){
                if (isNaN(row.longitude)) {return false;
                }
                else {return true;}
            });

            var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                      .domain([0, d3.max(rows, function(d) { return +d.population ;})])
                      .range([0, width]);

            svg.append("g")
               .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
               .call(d3.axisBottom(x));



            var histogram = d3.histogram()
                  .value(rows.population)
                  .domain(x.domain())
                  .thresholds(x.ticks(70));

            var bins = histogram(dataset);

            var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                      .range([height, 0])
                .domain([0, d3.max(bins, (d)=> d.length)]);

                svg.append("g")
                   .call(d3.axisLeft(y));



            svg.selectAll("rect")
              .data(bins)
              .enter()
              .append("rect")
                .attr("x", d => x(d.x0) + 1)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; })
                .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) -1 ; })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); })
                .style("fill", "#9b59b6 ")

  });
```

The following is the my `index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <title>Hello, France (D3)</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hello-france.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/histogram.js"></script>
    <div id="histogram-density"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I forgot to precise that I'm trying to draw an histogram of `population`, so the variable is `population` (see the dataset)

Comment: A couple questions: 1) what errors show in your console? 2) is your console logging the number of rows loaded? 3) is the relative path to your copy of d3.js correct?

Comment: 1) there is no error in the console, nothing, 2) yes my console is logging correctly the loaded rows, yes hello-france.js does draw a map but histogram.js doesn't, knowing that they are in the same folder js

Comment: `<div id="histogram-density"></div>` has to be before the script.